# How to find the common set of numbers in a 2D array?

Tags: java, arrays

I have a 2D array which if filled like this .

```
1 2 0 0 0 
1 2 0 0 0 
0 0 3 4 5 
0 0 3 4 5 
0 0 3 4 5
```

another example

```
1 2 3 0 
1 2 0 4 
1 0 3 4 
0 2 3 4
```

the code which I want to write is

searching about the maximum set of number repeated in the array .

in example 1 : the answer is 3 because the maximum is ( 3 4 5 ) repeted 3 times unlike ( 1 2 ) repeated just once .

Also in example 2,  the maximum is 2  because you will not have the same set of numbers repeated more than two times .

I want to write a code for that .

any help ?!

Comment: what I've tried  becomes a long long code  .

I have made an array for each number then compare these arrays and and taking the common of them .

Comment: Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works. You are expected to post a _concise_, _complete_ question, including your code reduced to the minimum needed to replicate the issue, explaining the problem, and detailing the steps you have tried to debug the issue.  SO is intended to be a resource for future visitors as well, not just for solving your specific problem.  Please visit the [help] and also read [ask] for more details.

Comment: I don't understand your examples and output. In the first example, 3 occurs the same number of times as 4 and 5. Technically, the answer should be 0. And all numbers occur the same number of times in the second example, but the answer again should be 0 since it occurs the most.

Comment: Jim Garrison , I am sorry but I will take care of that next time .

Comment: cricket_007 

Here I am looking for the maximum set repeated in the array 

in example 2 , the number 1 is repeated 3 times but ( 1 2 ) in the same time repeated just 2 times . also the other numbers ( 2 3 ) repeated just 2 times .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although this does not solve your issue directly, you can gather and count all sequences by assigning them as keys in a `Map`. After you do this, you can get the longest sequences and see which one has the highest frequency.

#### Output from Code Below

```
Sequence   Frequency
--------   ---------
2          2
5          3
1,2        2
3,4,5      3         // <- Longest sequence, Highest frequency.
4,5        3

Sequence   Frequency
--------   ---------
1          1
2          1
3          1
4          3         // <- Highest frequency, but not a sequence.
2,3,4      1
1,2        1
1,2,3      1
2,3        1
3,4        2         // <- Second highest frequency, is a sequence.
```

```java
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

public class MatrixSequenceFrequency {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] arr1 = new int[][] {
            { 1, 2, 0, 0, 0 },
            { 1, 2, 0, 0, 0 },
            { 0, 0, 3, 4, 5 },
            { 0, 0, 3, 4, 5 },
            { 0, 0, 3, 4, 5 }
        };

        printSequences(findSequences(arr1));

        int[][] arr2 = new int[][] {
            { 1, 2, 3, 0 },
            { 1, 2, 0, 4 },
            { 1, 0, 3, 4 },
            { 0, 2, 3, 4 }
        };

        printSequences(findSequences(arr2));
    }

    private static Map<String, Integer> findSequences(int[][] arr) {
        Map<String, Integer> sequences = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            indexSequences(arr[i], sequences);
        }

        return sequences;
    }

    private static void indexSequences(int[] arr, Map<String, Integer> sequences) {
        StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer();

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            for (int j = i; j < arr.length; j++) {
                if (arr[j] != 0) {
                    buff.append(arr[j]).append(',');
                } else {
                    break; // `0` breaks the sequence.
                }
            }

            if (buff.length() > 0) {
                if (buff.charAt(buff.length() - 1) == ',') {
                    buff.deleteCharAt(buff.length() - 1); // Remove extra comma.
                }

                Integer value = sequences.get(buff.toString());
                sequences.put(buff.toString(), value == null ? 1 : value + 1);
                buff.delete(0, buff.length()); // Clear Buffer
            }
        }
    }

    private static void printSequences(Map<String, Integer> sequences) {
        String format = "%-10s %s%n";
        System.out.printf(format, "Sequence", "Frequency");
        System.out.printf(format, "--------", "---------");
        for (Iterator<Entry<String, Integer>> it = sequences.entrySet().iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
            Entry<String, Integer> entry = it.next();
            System.out.printf(format, entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().toString());
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would filter through the array and add each number that is the same to a variable and then display the variable with the most hits

```
int three = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++){
     if(array.get(i) == 3){
        three++;
     }else if(array.get(i) == "Some other number"){
        number++;
      }
```

then you would need to filter through the numbers you just added up so

```
Collections.sort(arrayList); // Sort the arraylist
arrayList.get(arrayList.size() - 1); //gets the last item, largest for an ascending sort
```

then i would sort through the Array as to see how many are the same

```
if(arrayList.size() - 1 == arrayList.size() - 2){
   System.out.println(arrayList.size() - 1 " & " arrayList.size() - 2);
 }
```

There would be a lot more tedious coding but this would be the foundation of your code you first add the values to the variable and sort through the array list to see what value appeared the most and you would need a 2D Array for adding the actual variables we made at the start then sort them highest to lowest.

Comment: I think I didn't make my self clear . 

what I am trying to find is a set of numbers

Comment: You would just check to see what numbers all have the same value and the highest value. You could add them to an array list then display the highest values.

Comment: Totally right . 

I am looking for the maximum & biggest set repeated in the array in example 2 , the number 1 is repeated 3 times but  the set ( 1 2 ) in the same time repeated just 2 times . also the other numbers ( 2 3 ) or ( 3 4 )  repeated just 2 times
so the maximum is 2 .

Comment: i would add them to an array list then sort them in a collection then check to see if the first second third and fourth are the same ill put an example at the bottom

Comment: It seems to me ok ... I'll try it and I'll give my feedback .

Answer (score 0):

Here use this program

```
public class Matrix {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] a = new int[][] {
            { 1, 2, 3 },
            { 3, 3, 3 },
            { 1, 2, 3 }
        };
        int result = 0;
        int largestNum = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                if (result <= count(a[i][j], a)) {
                    result = count(a[i][j], a);
                    largestNum = a[i][j];
                }
            }
        }

        // Display the result
        System.out.println("Largest Number: " + largestNum);
    }

    public static int count(int arrVal, int[][] a) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                if (arrVal == a[i][j]) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }

        return count;
    }
}
```

For simplicity I have declared a 2d array of length 3 for both rows and columns. You can use array of any length

Comment: although this program gives result but this is not considered a good programming practice since it does redundant calculations.. you can optimize this, as I said earlier this is just for providing concept to the problem solution

Comment: Here the output always being 3

Comment: it`s because array 'a' has more number of 3